# Changing footnote symbol breaks \ref

Tags: symbols, footnotes, ref

I am using XeLaTex and the Memoir class. I redefined the footnote symbols like this:

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{{\ding{\numexpr171+\value{footnote}}}}
```

However, this breaks the \ref number when I put a label in a footnote. See the MWE below. It should say "See page 1 footnote 1" instead of "See page 1 footnote 2". I'm also using the perpage package and option, but the error occurs with or without it.

What is the correct way of doing it? Any help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{pifont} %Need circled numbers for Chinese style footnote 
\usepackage{perpage} %Renumber footnote on each new page
\usepackage{layouts} %To check page layout

%%% Book Layout %%%
\setstocksize{5in}{4in}
\settrimmedsize{5in}{4in}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\settypeblocksize{3in}{3in}{*}
\setulmargins{1in}{*}{*}
\setlrmargins{0.5in}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\checkandfixthelayout

%%% Footnote rule %%%
\MakePerPage{footnote}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{{\ding{\numexpr171+\value{footnote}}}}

\begin{document}

This is the first line\footnote{This is the first footnote.\label{ftn:first}}.

This is the second line\footnote{See page \pageref{ftn:first} footnote \ref{ftn:first}.}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@fnding}[1]{\ding{\number\numexpr#1+171\relax}}
\newcommand{\fnding}[1]{\expandafter\@fnding\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnding{footnote}}
```